# E_NOINTERFACE result from D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory

Tags: c++, directx-11

I'm just getting started with Dx11.  D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory is returning E_NOINTERFACE.

I know what E_NOINTERFACE means in terms of COM, but I don't know how to resolve this.  The shader compiler claims to have successfully compiled the shader code.

I'm loading the .fxo (complied shader) file into a buffer.  Stepping through the code, the debugger fails on the indicated line with the 0x8004002 error:

[image]

Sorry, the line indicated by the debugger is line 20 in the screenshot.

thanks for any insights

Comment: well, I've dropped the project back from VS2012 to VS2010 and the call succeeds.  It'd still be interesting to find out why the call is failing though.

Comment: which OS did you use? Windows 7?

Comment: compile source code(path\to\DirectX SDK\Samples\C++ \Effects11) by yourself and linked D3DX11EffectsD.lib

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error before, but with a different function, If you are using Windows 7, I guess this function was not supported, some interfaces only works on Windows 8, but MSDN does not describe it in details. take a look of [this question](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/108732.aspx) from the DirectX/XNA forum.

Comment: When I compile using the VS2010 compiler on the same platform, (hardware and OS the same) the function call succeeds.